# Node.js async filewriting (svg2img)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm facing a problem with writing files inside a svg2img code block.
Here is the code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    svg = barChartHelper.getBarChart({
      data: frames[i],
      width: 400,
      height: 300,
      xAxisLabel: '2012',
      yAxisLabel: 'Views',
      containerId: 'bar-chart-small'
    })
    console.log(i)
    svg2img(svg, function(error, buffer) {
      console.log("try to write file " + i);
      fs.writeFileSync('foo'+i+'.png', buffer, function(er){console.log(er)});
    });
    console.log(svg)
    fs.writeFile('frames/plot'+i+'.svg', svg, (er)=> console.log(er));
}
```

My problem is that in this way, the svg2img function only writes one file called `foo10.png` (10 times), instead of writing the files `foo0.png`until `foo9.png`. frames.length is 10.

I guess the svg2img function will be handled asynchronously, so it will be executed after the other functions in the loop. Inside the svg2img()-function i tried also the Async variant but no difference.

How can i write files foo0.png until foo9.png with different data (frames[i]) ?

Comment: Knowing what limitations you have would help - ES5/6/ etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use let instead of var, let block scoped which probably solve your problem,

```
for(let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    svg = barChartHelper.getBarChart({
      data: frames[i],
      width: 400,
      height: 300,
      xAxisLabel: '2012',
      yAxisLabel: 'Views',
      containerId: 'bar-chart-small'
    })
    console.log(i)
    svg2img(svg, function(error, buffer) {
      console.log("try to write file " + i);
      fs.writeFileSync('foo'+i+'.png', buffer, function(er){console.log(er)});
    });
    console.log(svg)
    fs.writeFile('frames/plot'+i+'.svg', svg, (er)=> console.log(er));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i solved it simalary, as you can see in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    svg = barChartHelper.getBarChart({
      data: frames[i],
      width: 400,
      height: 300,
      xAxisLabel: '2012',
      yAxisLabel: 'Views',
      containerId: 'bar-chart-small'
    })
    console.log(i);
    svg2img(svg, function(error, buffer) {
      console.log("try to write file " + i);
      fs.writeFile('foo'+i+'.png', buffer, function(er){console.log(er)});
    });
    console.log(svg)
    fs.writeFile('frames/plot'+i+'.svg', svg, (er)=> console.log(er));
  }
```

But i still don't understand why or how this had made the difference. Time for studying. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The step by step explanation what happens and why the real behavior is different from the expectations:

`1` iteration of for loop (`i = 0`):
`svg2img` takes `svg` and delegates converting it to another process

`2` iteration of for loop (`i = 1`):
`svg2img` takes `svg` and delegates converting it to another process

`n` iteration of for loop (`i = n - 1`):
`svg2img` takes `svg` and delegates converting it to another process

the loop ends and at this point `i` is equal to `frames.length`

the svg converting process of `1` ends and the callback is executed. The callback has a reference to `i` variable in the outer scope which has value of `frames.length` (the last value assigned to it)

the svg converting process of `n` ends and the callback is executed. The callback has a reference to `i` variable in the outer scope which has value of `frames.length` (the last value assigned to it)